# Increment and Decrement operators

Tags: c, operators, decrement

I am confused about the output of this program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i=2;
    while(i + 1?--i:14)
        printf("\n%d", i);

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program is printing `1` and not printing `1` and then `0`

When `i--` is used instead of `--i` it will print `1` and then `0`

Why is this?

- why in predecrementation it will print only `1` and not print `0`?
- and why in postdecrementation does it print `1` and then`0`?

Comment: Do `.` and `?` cost a lot to transmit on the net where you are?

Comment: Why would you need a reason?  Just write clearer code that does exactly what you want.  All code like this is just obfuscated rubbish and would get you fired in a professional environment.

Answer (score 5):

This is because `i--` results to give the value before the decrement operation will be performed. However, in `--i` i will be get decremented before its value will be used.

For understanding it better: 
Lets use your example:

```
 i=2;
```

Case 1:

```
while(i+1?--i:14)
```

First pass:
Condition `i+1?--i:14` will be evaluated as `2+1 ? 1 : 14`
This will return `1`. The loop will be executed and `i` will contain the value `1`.

Second pass:
Condition `i+1?--i:14` will be evaluated as `1+1 ? 0 : 14`
This will return `0`. Hence loop will not be executed, therefore you are getting output as `1`.

case 2:

```
while(i+1?i--:14)
```

First pass:
Condition `i+1?i--:14` will be evaluated as `2+1 ? 2-- : 14`
This will return `2`. The loop will be executed and `i` will contain the value `1`.

Second pass:
Condition `i+1?i--:14` will be evaluated as `2+1 ? 1-- : 14`
This will return `1`. The loop will be executed and `i` will contain the value `0`.

The `while` loop will be executed twice in this case.

Comment: but value of i is 2 then i-- must print 2..then 1 and 0..in i-- it will printing only 1 and 0 and in --i it will printing only 1 not printing 0..this is what i am confuse in it..

Comment: @user3485153 No, because `i--` is done in the loop *condition* so inside the loop `i` is the decreased value.

Comment: you mean to say that in while first i-- will decreased that value and then assign to i and then it will decremented?

Comment: @user3485153 Pre-decrement (e.g. `--i`) is straight forward, it like "decrease `i` then return new value of `i`". Post-decrement (e.g. `i--`) is like "save `i` to a temporary value, decrease `i`, return temporary value (i.e. old value of `i`)".

Comment: Correction: `--i` will *evaluate* to `i-1`, but it's not guaranteed that `i` will be decremented immediately upon evaluation; the only guarantee is that it will be decremented before the next sequence point.  This is part of why expressions like `--i * --i` are bad juju.

Answer (score 2):

Lets take this in order:

1. `i == 2`, which means that `i + 1` is `3` (and non-zero so true) and the loop uses `--i` for condition which decreases `i` to `1` which is true and the loop runs
2. `i == 1`, which means that `i + 1` is `2` (also true), and the loop uses `--i` for condition which decreases `i` to zero which is false and the loop exits.

---

If on the other hand you use the post-decrement its like this:

1. `i == 2`, which means that `i + 1` is `3` (and non-zero so true) and the loop uses `i--` for condition which "returns" `2` (and as it's "true" runs the loop) and *then* decreases `i` to `1`
2. `i == 1`, which means that `i + 1` is `2` (and true) and the loop uses `i--` which "returns" `1` (and as it's "true" runs the loop) and then decreases `i` to zero
3. `i == 0`, which means that `i + 1` is `1` (and true) and the loop uses `i--` which "returns" zero (and ends the loop) and then decrease `i` to `-1`.